# OrmLite SqlList<T> doesn't work with nullable enum property?

Tags: c#, mysql, enums, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

OrmLite **SqlList** doesn't work with **nullable enum** property?

```
public static List<T> SqlList<T> (this IDbConnection dbConn, string sql, object anonType = null);
```

If I have an enum like so

```
public enum WorkStatus
{
    Started = 0,
    Ended = 1
}
```

And I have an object like so

```
public class Query
{
    //nullable enum won't work
    public WorkStatus? NotWork { get; set; }

    //but non nullable enum will work
    public WorkStatus Work { get; set; }
}
```

When I do

```
//conn is of type IDbConnection
//ignored where clause in raw sql just for the simplicity
conn.SqlList<T>(@"select * from works", new Query());
```

If I only have the non nullable enum the query works fine, if I only have the nullable enum, the query will throw exceptions

> LEVEL:ERROR CLASS:ServiceStack.DtoUtils ServiceBase::Service Exception
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr2/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/throwhelper.cs:70
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.Type, System.Data.DbType>.get_Item (System.Type) [0x00021] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr2/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs:176
>   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteDialectProviderBase`1.GetColumnDbType (System.Type) <0x00093>

I'm on mono but I doubt this will be the cause. Database is mysql. It kind of sounds like nullable enum isn't supported by "GetColumnDbType ".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the latest version and do you have a complete example as [this test below works in all Databases](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/33b737ad5fe89f08f33a64aa9e02aed74fbfdce1):

```
var db = OpenDbConnection();

db.DropAndCreateTable<TypeWithNullableEnum>();

db.Insert(new TypeWithNullableEnum { Id = 1, 
    EnumValue = SomeEnum.Value1, NullableEnumValue = SomeEnum.Value2 });
db.Insert(new TypeWithNullableEnum { Id = 2, EnumValue = SomeEnum.Value1 });

var rows = db.Select<TypeWithNullableEnum>();
Assert.That(rows.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));

var row = rows.First(x => x.NullableEnumValue == null);
Assert.That(row.Id, Is.EqualTo(2));

var quotedTable = typeof(TypeWithNullableEnum).Name.SqlTable();

rows = db.SqlList<TypeWithNullableEnum>("SELECT * FROM {0}".Fmt(quotedTable));

row = rows.First(x => x.NullableEnumValue == null);
Assert.That(row.Id, Is.EqualTo(2));

rows = db.SqlList<TypeWithNullableEnum>("SELECT * FROM {0}"
    .Fmt(quotedTable), new { Id = 2 });

row = rows.First(x => x.NullableEnumValue == null);
Assert.That(row.Id, Is.EqualTo(2));
```

Comment: Correction: I'm using 4.0.36. I'll check out the latest version and see if issue persists.

Comment: Yes there's no issue with 4.0.42. Was this feature (nullable<enum>) not supported for 4.0.36?

Comment: @Jeff v4.0.36 was released 6+ months ago, its likely the issue has been resolved since then. Though it's unusual to have nullable enums, normally you'd use one of the enumeration values to denote a default/empty value.

Comment: The reason we are using nullable<enum> is because it can enable us to do "filtering" like in the following sql (i.e. the where clause).

"select w.Blah,w.Blah1,w.Blah2,w.Status from works w where(@Status is null or w.Status = @Status)"

Comment: Unfortunately we have to write "raw sql" and call "SqlList<T>" to "execute" the raw sql. It'll be a lot easier if we can operate on your SqlExpression but that's not the case for now.

Comment: And in our case we can't have a None or All enum status, because this enum is "exposed" to the UI, and we don't want to have to manually filter out this None or All enum value.

Comment: Not saying there's no better way, I was only describing what's been done. Thanks once again for your timely response! ServiceStack is awesome!